# bootstrap multilevel dropdown in navbar has unwanted empty space

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have bootstrap multilevel drop down navbar. when I click on the button I want the sub menu to drop right side of the list but it is overlapping last option. can anyone suggest me how to do it?
[image]
[image]

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-lg-4">  
  <li class="active dropdown yamm-fw">
  <a href="index.php" data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" 
href="#"> category <span class="caret"></span> </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropright">
  <?php $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select id,categoryName  from category 
limit 10");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{       
   $category_name=$row['categoryName'];
  if ( $category_name == "Clothing")
   { ?>
 <li class="dropdown yamm btn-group">
 <a class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> <?php echo 
 $category_name; ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu dropright">
 <?php $sql1=mysqli_query($con,"select id,subcategory  from subcategory1 
 where categoryid=" .$row['id']);
 while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1))
  { ?>
 <li class="dropdown yamm">
 <a  href="category.php?cid=<?php echo $row1['id'];?>"> <?php echo 
 $row1['subcategory'];?></a>
 </li>
 <?php } ?>
 </ul>
  </li>
    <?php } 
    else
          { ?>
      <li class="dropdown yamm">
        <a href="category.php?cid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"> <?php echo 
         $row['categoryName'];?></a>
        </li>
          <?php 
           }
           } ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: How is this related to MySQL?

Comment: All the categories are stored in mysql database and can be added from the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

You may overcome this problem by writing the CSS the value of paddings.

```css
    .nav li {padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;}
```

Also, have look at line-height property it might be create some problem. on some cases.